# on click on the image to change that image state(enable or disable the image color change)

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Following this [Documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/web-view) I can do button color change when user move to previous page and come back again . Like changing its state.

I want to do the same thing with image. I didn't see any official documentation to change image state.

```
<Image isEnabled="enabled" src="res://logo_white_bg" class="btn-back" height="35"
 width="35" row="0" col="0" (tap)="goBack()"></Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Behind `isEnabled` stands native logic for creating the visual effect of enabling and disabling **some** of the UI controls (but not all UI elements supports `isEnabled`). However, I don't believe this is supported for images on both iOS and Android so it is expected no to have isEnabled functionality for the image element.

Following the very same binding logic (with setting a bound `enabled` boolean to true or false during navigation) you could directly change the `src` of your Image.

```
// I guess something like this should do the trick (pseudo code)

if (this.enabled) {
  this.myImageSrc = "<the-enabled-image-URI>.jpg";
} else if(!this.enabled) {
  this.myImageSrc = "<the-disabled-image-URI>.jpg";
}
```

And instead of using `isEnabled`  directly bind the `myImageSrc`

```
<Image [src]="myImageSrc"></Image>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i couldn't change the state of the image